# CI: Protect views with session

Tags: codeigniter

I was playing around a bit with CodeIgniter, I was trying to overwrite the default CI_Controller in orde to create some sort of tempting system.

But now I ran into a problem, my site will have a different layout for visitors, once a user is logged in, the layout will change to something else.
What would be the best way to implement this, would I create an array and than check if that view is accessible for users?

Let's say the user goes to www.site.com/index.php/dashboard, /dashboard should only be visible to logged in users, how would I be able to check this?

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{  
public function __construct() 
{
    parent::__construct();
}

function _output($content)
{
    // Load the base template with output content available as $content
    $data['content'] = &$content;
    echo($this->load->view('html_guest', $data, true));
}

private function _check_auth()
{

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I have been looking for the same for long, for one good and strong practice to have multiple authentication level with different views, access ... etc

one of the best guide here

http://jondavidjohn.com/blog/2011/01/scalable-login-system-for-codeigniter-ion_auth

Read it step by step and 10 minutes you should have got it

Answer (score 1):

You could use a ready made templating library like [this one](http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/).

Then based on a check (for example; is logged in)in your controller set the default template to use (ref section I. Configuration).